# Train the model first and Test multiple times

Tags: python, command-line, nlp

I have been trying to use python's NLP script with my QT GUI based C++ application. 
Basically in the application I am trying to access the NLP script through command line:

```
QString path = "D:/DS Project/Treegramming";
QString  command("py");
QStringList params = QStringList() << "nlp.py";
params << text;
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->setWorkingDirectory(path);
process->start(command, params);
process->waitForFinished();
QString result = process->readAll();
```

The above is working perfectly. but the problem is, it is taking about 40-50 seconds to execute, as it is first training the model and then testing.
But I want to train the model first and test it multiple times as we do in Jupyter Notebook.
for that I made a separate function for testing and trying to access it with command line:

> PS D:\DS Project\Treegramming> py nlp.py "test('it was amazing')"

but again this thing is executing the whole script first and then executing the function. is there anything I can do to solve this?

python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Dec  6 16:18:01 2019

@author: Muhammad Ahmed
"""

import nltk
import sys
import random
import re,string
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples
from nltk import classify
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

positive_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('positive_tweets.json')
negative_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('negative_tweets.json')
text = twitter_samples.strings('tweets.20150430-223406.json')

tweet_tokens = twitter_samples.tokenized('positive_tweets.json')

def lemmatize_sentence(tokens):
    sentence = []
    lematizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    for word, tag in pos_tag(tokens):
        if tag.startswith('NN'):
            pos = 'n'
        elif tag.startswith('VB'):
            pos = 'v'
        else:
            pos = 'a'
        sentence.append( lematizer.lemmatize( word , pos ) )
    return sentence

def remove_noise(tokens , stop_words = ()):
    sentence = []
    for token, tag in pos_tag( tokens ):
        token = re.sub('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+#]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+' , '',token)
        token = re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9_]+)","",token)

        if tag.startswith("NN"):
            pos = 'n'
        elif tag.startswith('VB'):
            pos = 'v'
        else:
            pos = 'a'

        lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
        token = lemmatizer.lemmatize(token, pos)

        if len(token) > 0 and token not in string.punctuation and token.lower() not in stop_words:
            sentence.append( token.lower() )
    return sentence

def get_all_words(tokens_list):
    for tokens in tokens_list:
        for token in tokens:
            yield token

def get_tweets_for_model(tokens_list):
    for tweets in tokens_list:
        yield dict([token,True] for token in tweets)

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

positive_tweet_tokens = twitter_samples.tokenized('positive_tweets.json')
negative_tweet_tokens = twitter_samples.tokenized('negative_tweets.json')

positive_cleaned_tokens_list = []
negative_cleaned_tokens_list = []

for tokens in positive_tweet_tokens:
    positive_cleaned_tokens_list.append(remove_noise(tokens, stop_words))

for tokens in negative_tweet_tokens:
    negative_cleaned_tokens_list.append(remove_noise(tokens, stop_words))

all_pos_words = get_all_words( positive_cleaned_tokens_list )
all_neg_words = get_all_words( negative_cleaned_tokens_list )

freq_dis_pos = FreqDist( all_pos_words )
freq_dis_neg = FreqDist( all_neg_words )

positive_tokens_for_model = get_tweets_for_model(positive_cleaned_tokens_list)
negative_tokens_for_model = get_tweets_for_model(negative_cleaned_tokens_list)

pos_dataset = [(tweets,"Positive") for tweets in positive_tokens_for_model]
neg_dataset = [(tweets,"Negative") for tweets in negative_tokens_for_model]

dataset = pos_dataset + neg_dataset
random.shuffle(dataset)

train_data = dataset[:7000]
test_data = dataset[7000:]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)

def test( custom_tweet ):
    custom_tokens = remove_noise(word_tokenize(custom_tweet))
    res = classifier.classify(dict([token, True] for token in custom_tokens))
    print(res)
    f = open( "result.txt" , "w" )
    f.write(res)    
    f.close() 

eval( sys.argv[1] );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two python scripts:

- First to **train** and **save** the NaiveBayesClassifier
- Second to **load** and **test** the model.

To prevent repeating code, I will create a script for helpful functions and I will call it `utils.py` which should look like this:

```
import re
import string
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

def lemmatize_sentence(tokens):
    sentence = []
    lematizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    for word, tag in pos_tag(tokens):
        if tag.startswith('NN'):
            pos = 'n'
        elif tag.startswith('VB'):
            pos = 'v'
        else:
            pos = 'a'
        sentence.append( lematizer.lemmatize( word , pos ) )
    return sentence

def remove_noise(tokens , stop_words = ()):
    sentence = []
    for token, tag in pos_tag( tokens ):
        token = re.sub('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+#]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+' , '',token)
        token = re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9_]+)","",token)

        if tag.startswith("NN"):
            pos = 'n'
        elif tag.startswith('VB'):
            pos = 'v'
        else:
            pos = 'a'

        lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
        token = lemmatizer.lemmatize(token, pos)

        if len(token) > 0 and token not in string.punctuation and token.lower() not in stop_words:
            sentence.append( token.lower() )
    return sentence

def get_all_words(tokens_list):
    for tokens in tokens_list:
        for token in tokens:
            yield token

def get_tweets_for_model(tokens_list):
    for tweets in tokens_list:
        yield dict([token,True] for token in tweets)
```

Then let's create the training script, I will call it `train.py` and it should look like this:

```
import random
import pickle
from utils import *
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples


positive_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('positive_tweets.json')
negative_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('negative_tweets.json')
text = twitter_samples.strings('tweets.20150430-223406.json')

tweet_tokens = twitter_samples.tokenized('positive_tweets.json')

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

positive_tweet_tokens = twitter_samples.tokenized('positive_tweets.json')
negative_tweet_tokens = twitter_samples.tokenized('negative_tweets.json')

positive_cleaned_tokens_list = []
negative_cleaned_tokens_list = []

for tokens in positive_tweet_tokens:
    positive_cleaned_tokens_list.append(remove_noise(tokens, stop_words))

for tokens in negative_tweet_tokens:
    negative_cleaned_tokens_list.append(remove_noise(tokens, stop_words))

all_pos_words = get_all_words( positive_cleaned_tokens_list )
all_neg_words = get_all_words( negative_cleaned_tokens_list )

freq_dis_pos = FreqDist( all_pos_words )
freq_dis_neg = FreqDist( all_neg_words )

positive_tokens_for_model = get_tweets_for_model(positive_cleaned_tokens_list)
negative_tokens_for_model = get_tweets_for_model(negative_cleaned_tokens_list)

pos_dataset = [(tweets,"Positive") for tweets in positive_tokens_for_model]
neg_dataset = [(tweets,"Negative") for tweets in negative_tokens_for_model]

dataset = pos_dataset + neg_dataset
random.shuffle(dataset)

train_data = dataset[:7000]
test_data = dataset[7000:]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)

#### ADD THESE TO SAVE THE CLASSIFIER ####
with open("model.pickle", "wb") as fout:
    pickle.dump(classifier, fout)
```

Finally, the test script `test.py` that should look like this:

```
import sys
import pickle
from nltk import classify
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

from utils import remove_noise

#### ADD THESE TO LOAD THE CLASSIFIER ####
with open('model.pickle', 'rb') as fin:
    classifier = pickle.load(fin)


def test( custom_tweet ):
    custom_tokens = remove_noise(word_tokenize(custom_tweet))
    res = classifier.classify(dict([token, True] for token in custom_tokens))
    print(res)
    f = open( "result.txt" , "w" )
    f.write(res)    
    f.close() 

eval( sys.argv[1] );
```

Now, run `train.py` once to train the Naive Bayes classifier that will create a new file called `model.pickle` that holds the trained classifier. Then run `test.py` from your C++ application on your custom tweet. `test.py` should loades the trained model `model.pickle` and use it on the given custom tweet.